# Receiving 403 from Googlemaps

Tags: python, google-maps, network-programming

I try to learn python network programming from book "**Foundation of Python Network Programming**"     Apres,

first we learn about '**virtualenv**' and I install virtualenv , try to get '**googlemap package**' and try using simple program call 'search1' :

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python 
 # Foundations of Python Network Programming - Chapter 1 - search1.py 

 from googlemaps import GoogleMaps 
 address = '207 N. Defiance St, Archbold, OH' 

 print GoogleMaps().address_to_latlng(address)
```

after that I try running it,

1. **the result from the book is**

   $ python search1.py
   (41.5228242, -84.3063479)
2. **the result I get is error liket this**

   Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "search1.py", line 6, in 
       print GoogleMaps().address_to_latlng(address)

   File "/home/administrator/gmapenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googlemaps.py", line 310, in address_to_latlng

   return tuple(self.geocode(address)['Placemark'][0]['Point']['coordinates'][1::-1])

   File "/home/administrator/gmapenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googlemaps.py", line 259, in geocode

   url, response = fetch_json(self._GEOCODE_QUERY_URL, params=params)

   File "/home/administrator/gmapenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googlemaps.py", line 50, in fetch_json
       response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
       return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)

   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in open
       response = meth(req, response)

   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 520, in http_response
       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)

   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 445, in error
       return self._call_chain(*args)

   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 379, in _call_chain
       result = func(*args)

   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 528, in http_error_default
       raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
   urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

What make this error , because it I run down step by step like in the book

Comment: Your system has access to the google url ?

Comment: yes i have connection with internet

Comment: connection with internet doesnt mean you have access to that url. Please check once is there any firewall or ISP policy which might be blocking this url.

Comment: I still confuse here what URL in this ? can you elaborate

Comment: `googlemaps` package internally call `maps.google.com` webservice API  and return you result. Pleas try to do `wget www.maps.google.com` form your console.

Comment: This is what 403 for `A web server may return a 403 Forbidden HTTP status code in response to a request from a client for a web page or resource to indicate that the server can be reached and understood the request, but refuses to take any further action. Status code 403 responses are the result of the web server being configured to deny access, for some reason, to the requested resource by the client.`

Comment: this is the result :                                           Connecting to maps.google.com (maps.google.com)|74.125.130.100|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html'

    [  <=>                                  ] 126,831      369K/s   in 0.3s

2014-08-06 00:38:17 (369 KB/s) - `index.html' saved [126831]

Comment: `403` means you have access but server refuse to take any action. Check is there any `apikey` or some other data you have to provide ?

Comment: I search in google that google maps are change                      The Geocoding API v2 has been turned down on September 9th, 2013. The Geocoding API v3 should be used now.                                         because this book and the code is from 2010 , what do you think

Comment: I also get same error `
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
`

Comment: I get from this site http://jianshu.io/p/d100dadeabde

Comment: Yes that might be problem, api was down.

Comment: Thank you for the response Lafada